# Link over image

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I want to put text (link) over a image. I know about the position:absolute, position: relative and z-index, but doesn't work.

```css
ul {
  margin: 15px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 95%;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #282828;
}

li:hover img {
  opacity: 0.1;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section id="container>
        <div class=" wrap ">
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="# "><img src="img/hello.jpg " alt=" ">Text</a></li>
                        <li><a href="# "><img src="img/hello.jpg " alt=" ">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="# "><img src="img/hello.jpg " alt=" ">Text</a></li>
                        <li><a href="# "><img src="img/hello.jpg " alt=" ">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="# "><img src="img/hello.jpg " alt=" ">Text</a></li>
                        <li><a href="# "><img src="img/hello.jpg " alt=" ">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="# "><img src="img/hello.jpg " alt=" ">Text</a></li>
                        <li><a href="# "><img src="img/hello.jpg " alt=" ">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="# "><img src="img/hello.jpg " alt=" ">Text</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: What, exactly, "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a { padding-bottom: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just see the output on below page.
**Note** I have set the inline style only for one li. You can add the same to others

http://jsfiddle.net/P2Uy9/

```
   <li><a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRnxWPtKJdW10x5Ar3eYP9zT44CCojcLQcnETwx-TaG9Pb6ttxSvRbX3H0" alt=""><span style="position:relative;bottom:30px;">Text</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your link text with an html tag like this ([Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6MRLM/2/)):

```
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="img/hello.jpg" alt=""><span>Text</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Then following CSS additions:

```
a {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #282828;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    padding: 25px 10px;
    }
img {
   max-width: 100%;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index:99;
}
a span {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index:999;
}
```

Comment: This is what happens. https://www.dropbox.com/s/cxlh3ti1c6azto6/Screen%20Shot%202013-11-30%20at%2002.10.38.png Wired